Springdoc apidocs display yaml by default instead of json
I have a Spring Boot 3.x application using Springdoc to generate Swagger and OpenAPI documentation. When I access /api-docs, it returns the schema in JSON format. To get the YAML format, I have to append .yaml to the URL, like /api-docs.yaml.
Is there a way to configure Springdoc to return the YAML schema by default when accessing /api-docs, without having to append .yaml to the URL? I want YAML to be the default format instead of JSON.
I tried adding a custom controller, but it doesn't work. And adding a filter in my sprindoc config class but none works, I'm still having json as default.

Here is the @RestController used to generate the api-docs. You can see that the resource is actually mapped to two different path. You can also see that there isn't a property to configure this easily.
What you can do, is deactivating the default /api-docs by setting this property springdoc.enable-default-api-docs to false.
And then declare your own @RestController which replace the json endpoint by the yaml one (DEFAULT_API_DOCS_URL_YAML => API_DOCS_URL)

import static org.springdoc.core.utils.Constants.API_DOCS_URL;
import static org.springdoc.core.utils.Constants.APPLICATION_OPENAPI_YAML;

@RestController
public class MyOpenApiWebMvcResource extends OpenApiResource {

  /**
   * Instantiates a new Open api web mvc resource.
   *
   * @param groupName the group name
   * @param openAPIBuilderObjectFactory the open api builder object factory
   * @param requestBuilder the request builder
   * @param responseBuilder the response builder
   * @param operationParser the operation parser
   * @param springDocConfigProperties the spring doc config properties
   * @param springDocProviders the spring doc providers
   * @param springDocCustomizers the spring doc customizers
   */
  public OpenApiWebMvcResource(
      String groupName,
      ObjectFactory<OpenAPIService> openAPIBuilderObjectFactory,
      AbstractRequestService requestBuilder,
      GenericResponseService responseBuilder,
      OperationService operationParser,
      SpringDocConfigProperties springDocConfigProperties,
      SpringDocProviders springDocProviders,
      SpringDocCustomizers springDocCustomizers) {
    super(
        groupName,
        openAPIBuilderObjectFactory,
        requestBuilder,
        responseBuilder,
        operationParser,
        springDocConfigProperties,
        springDocProviders,
        springDocCustomizers);
  }

  /**
   * Instantiates a new Open api web mvc resource.
   *
   * @param openAPIBuilderObjectFactory the open api builder object factory
   * @param requestBuilder the request builder
   * @param responseBuilder the response builder
   * @param operationParser the operation parser
   * @param springDocConfigProperties the spring doc config properties
   * @param springDocProviders the spring doc providers
   * @param springDocCustomizers the spring doc customizers
   */
  @Autowired
  public OpenApiWebMvcResource(
      ObjectFactory<OpenAPIService> openAPIBuilderObjectFactory,
      AbstractRequestService requestBuilder,
      GenericResponseService responseBuilder,
      OperationService operationParser,
      SpringDocConfigProperties springDocConfigProperties,
      SpringDocProviders springDocProviders,
      SpringDocCustomizers springDocCustomizers) {
    super(
        openAPIBuilderObjectFactory,
        requestBuilder,
        responseBuilder,
        operationParser,
        springDocConfigProperties,
        springDocProviders,
        springDocCustomizers);
  }

  /**
   * Openapi yaml string.
   *
   * @param request the request
   * @param apiDocsUrl the api docs url
   * @param locale the locale
   * @return the string
   * @throws JsonProcessingException the json processing exception
   */
  @Operation(hidden = true)
  @GetMapping(value = API_DOCS_URL, produces = APPLICATION_OPENAPI_YAML)
  @Override
  public byte[] openapiYaml(
      HttpServletRequest request, @Value(API_DOCS_URL) String apiDocsUrl, Locale locale)
      throws JsonProcessingException {
    return super.openapiYaml(request, apiDocsUrl, locale);
  }

  /**
   * Gets server url.
   *
   * @param request the request
   * @param apiDocsUrl the api docs url
   * @return the server url
   */
  @Override
  protected String getServerUrl(HttpServletRequest request, String apiDocsUrl) {
    String requestUrl = decode(request.getRequestURL().toString());
    Optional<SpringWebProvider> springWebProviderOptional =
        springDocProviders.getSpringWebProvider();
    String prefix = StringUtils.EMPTY;
    if (springWebProviderOptional.isPresent())
      prefix = springWebProviderOptional.get().findPathPrefix(springDocConfigProperties);
    return requestUrl.substring(0, requestUrl.length() - apiDocsUrl.length() - prefix.length());
  }
}

